# Are there Cmdlets equivalent to $Host.UI.Prompt() and $Host.UI.PromptForChoice()?

Tags: powershell

The `$host.UI.PromptForCredential()` method has an equivalent cmdlet Get-Credential.
Do `$host.UI.Prompt()` and `$host.UI.PromptForChoice()` also have equivalent cmdlets?

Comment: My gut says no. There _might_ be one in a 3rd party repository PSCX but those are not native like `Get-Credential`. You probably just need to make your own.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in native Powershell that I know of is `Out-GridView` in V3 and later versions:

```
Get-Childitem *.txt | select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Out-GridView -Title 'Select file(s) to open.' -OutputMode Multiple |
foreach {& Notepad $_ }
```

Comment: Not quite what I was after but it may be useful in other circumstances.  Cheers.